# How to preload iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-animate, preload

```
function toggle(){
    $("#tempc").toggle(
        function () {
            $("#tempc").animate({width: 255, height: 220}, 1000);
            $("#tempc").html("");
            $("#tempc").css("background-color", "transparent");
            $("#tempc").html("<iframe src='/src/stream.php?stream=1' width='255' height='225' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe><br><a href='javascript:;' onclick='hidegadget();' class='yellowblock'>Sluit</a>");
        },
        function () {
            $("#tempc").animate({width: 50, height:50}, 1000);
            $("#tempc").html("");
            $("#tempc").css("background-color", "#FFFF00");

            $.get('src/stream.php?stream=2', function(data002) {
                $('#tempc').html(data002);
            });
        }
    );
}

$.get('src/stream.php?stream=2', function(data002) {
    $('#tempc').html(data002);
});
```

A while ago I was trying to animate a div, well, it works now only one thing.
When the first function is activated (starting row 3),  and iframe gets loaded. But now, how can I preload that iframe? Because when the animation is finished the iframe isn't loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JQuery, you don't need to use iframes. Take a look at the .load() function. http://api.jquery.com/load

i.e.

```
$('#tempc').load('src/stream.php?stream=1');
```

To preload a page, just create a hidden div and show it when ready.

```
var stream2 = $('<div>').load('src/stream.php?stream=2').hide();
$('#tempc').html(stream2.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by loading the iframe, hook into `onLoad` on the iframe (this might give you a headache in itself, but a little googling should show you how to make this work well cross browser) and run your animation from this event.