# pre-load fancybox iframe

Tags: iframe, preload, fancybox-2

I have an fancybox iframe,
Is there a way to pre-load the content of the iframe before the link is clicked open? The iframe content is a script, not images.

SCRIPT:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({ 
fitToView: false, 
afterLoad: function(){
this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
this.height = $(this.element).data("height"); }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-width="950" data-height="90%" href="/?page_id=1508" >MLS® SEARCH</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4891411/1055987

Comment: could you code something on http://jsfiddle.net ? its easier to help you with a semi-working sample